How to measure and mark for a hinge?
How should I measure and mark the position of a hinge, attaching a folding shelf to a table, so that 1) the top surfaces are flush, and 2) the gap is minimized without binding?
The table and shelf are both large and unwieldy.  I cannot do this in place.

I think the way to do it is to make a couple of simple jigs?   The shelf can go upside down in a known inside right angle and the hinge marked there?  I  can set the gap by sliding the shelf away from the jig's inside corner.  For the table, a small piece of the shelf material can be attached to a board, the board placed on the table with the small piece hanging down, and the hinge placed up against it for marking.

Is there an easier or better way?

The gap could be zero, so marking and attaching that should be extremely easy. Once you have that, proceed with clamps and your second picture to mark and attach.

How much prior research did you do on installing hinges jay613? Once you're au fait with installing butt hinges in general (including allowing for the knuckle if it's necessary, as it appears to be here) it should pretty much obviate the need for a Q. Especially since you've already thought it through enough to use a scrap to more easily set hinge position on the table side of things. However... "I cannot do this in place." I think you can but more so, should. It shouldn't be too hard to figure out how to use e.g. 2 or 3 boards + clamps to provide the equivalent of an extra pair of hands.

I am confused.  Why can't you turn the table upside down on a flat surface and position the shelf next to it, make your marks and attach the shelf?

@Ashlar the table is large and heavy and has shelves that are occupied by heavy things.   I really hadn't considered this.   In my present problem it may in fact be the easiest way.    So thank you for stating what should have been obvious.   But I wrote the question intentionally imagining the "table" to be whatever large immobile thing you want, and trying to figure out how to work with these hinges.  There's lots of material on the web about using them for cabinet doors but not much for flaps.

@Graphus saying that if I have sufficient general experience, I should be able to figure out the answer, is factual but not in keeping with the site guidelines as I understand them.   We already have two good answers here in the comments.  That they were not obvious to me does not make the question worse.  As for my research there is plenty of stuff on how to mortise the hinges and how to align them for cabinet doors but my particular question is not well covered. Have a look.

I was not saying that you needed to have sufficient general experience, but that you should have done sufficient prior research. Like I said I think this would have removed the need to ask this in the first place, certainly in this form. As someone with far more rep than I put it on another stack Diligent research is required before asking a question. And furthermore the body text should show that this has been done. You'll forgive me, but as written it would appear you did no prior research before writing the Q. [Not a personal attack, just an observation based on what we can see.]

"but my particular question is not well covered" Actually it is if you think about it in another way, as a problem rotated 90°...... hanging a door. A door frame is essentially your immovable table, and the door your unwieldy too large/too heavy shelf. Now nobody is installing a door without supporting its weight somehow right? Same deal here, just different orientation and different supports needed (with tip on how already given). Once all weight is taken off the shelf (and presumably it's held in place in the other axes too) the problem becomes much simpler.
